# Web Scrape Numbers in R?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

In R, I am trying to webscrape the all **working paper #** (e.g, 31424, 31481, etc) of the following webpage:

https://www.nber.org/papers?facet=topics%3AFinancial%20Economics&page=1&perPage=50&sortBy=public_date

I trying to run the following code to get such:

```
url<-"https://www.nber.org/papers?facet=topics%3AFinancial%20Economics&page=1&perPage=50&sortBy=public_date"
page=read_html(url)
name=page%>%html_nodes(".paper-card__paper_number")%>%html_text()
```

However, this code returns **character(0)**, NOT giving me the working paper #'s. Is there any way I can **modify this code to get the working paper #'s**?

Comment: If you open the source of the page, you'll see that the element you want isn't there. That's because it's instead being loaded by JavaScript, which rvest isn't able to interact with. You'll instead need to use something like RSelenium. Here's [one tutorial](https://thatdatatho.com/tutorial-web-scraping-rselenium/) that might help.

Comment: As with your previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76757814/web-scrape-hyperlinked-text-in-r - that content is not included in the page source but fetched by javascript running in your browser, so rvest doesn't have much to work with here.  You can extract those numbers from URLs  you got from the previous answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76758080/646761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To scrape dynamically generated content, you can use a headless browser automation tool like RSelenium, which allows you to control a real web browser programmatically. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

1.First, make sure you have RSelenium and rvest installed:

```
install.packages("RSelenium")
install.packages("rvest")
```

2.Load the required libraries:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
```

3.Start a Selenium server and open a browser:

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", chromever="latest", port=4567L)
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
```

4.Navigate to the desired URL:

```
url <- "https://www.nber.org/papers?facet=topics%3AFinancial%20Economics&page=1&perPage=50&sortBy=public_date"
remDr$navigate(url)
```

5.Get the working paper numbers:

```
page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
page <- read_html(page_source)
name <- page %>% html_nodes(".paper-card__paper_number") %>% html_text()
```

6.Stop the Selenium server and close the browser:

```
remDr$close()
driver$server$stop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just had one question. Is there a way to tell if webpages contain dynamically generated content like this, so that I know when I need to use RSelenium?

Comment: if data getting via post request or any secure source then need to use RSelenium. everything based on website

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to Selenium is to query NBER's restful API, which will return a rather simple json, with a data.frame like object that holds not just the Working Paper number but a lot of usefull information, like authors, title, date, etc...
Accessing an API is much faster than recurring to Selenium because the server returns much less data to the clients.

The API allows you to paginate, with each query returning up to 100 results. You can get the API's url by inspecting the network traffic of your web browser session.

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
    
url_to_json <- "https://www.nber.org/api/v1/working_page_listing/contentType/working_paper/_/_/search?facet=topics%3AFinancial%20Economics&page=1&perPage=100&sortBy=public_date"
json_p01    <- fromJSON(txt = url_to_json) 

df_p01 <- as_tibble(json_p01$results) |> 
          mutate(wp_id = sub(pattern = "^.*papers[/]w", replacement = "", url))

df_p01 |> select(displaydate, title, wp_id, abstract)
# A tibble: 100 × 4
   displaydate title                                      wp_id abstract
   <chr>       <chr>                                      <chr> <chr>   
 1 July 2023   The Impact of Money in Politics on Labor … 31481 We exam…
 2 July 2023   Aggregate Lending and Modern Financial In… 31484 Existin…
 3 July 2023   Financial Machine Learning                 31502 We surv…
 4 July 2023   Housing, Household Debt, and the Business… 31489 China a…
 5 July 2023   Selection-Neglect in the NFT Bubble        31498 Using t…
 6 July 2023   Social Security Claiming Intentions: Psyc… 31499 For man…
 7 July 2023   Sparse Modeling Under Grouped Heterogenei… 31424 Sparse …
 8 July 2023   Firms with Benefits? Nonwage Compensation… 31463 Using a…
 9 July 2023   The Credit Supply Channel of Monetary Pol… 31464 This pa…
10 July 2023   Bank Branch Density and Bank Runs          31462 Bank br…
# ℹ 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

### If you need to capture a second page, then paginate by modifying the URL.

```
library(urltools)
url_to_json_page_2 <- urltools::param_set(urls = url_to_json,  key = "page", value = 2)
```